# Getting the wrong timestamp after combining columns Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I managed to combine a year, month, and day column into 1 and then combining that with a time column. When I try to convert it to a timestamp, I'm getting the wrong one. Here is my code that I tried.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("full_date", concat_ws("/", $"Month", $"Day", $"Year"))
// // df2.show()
val df3 = df2.withColumn("date_time", concat_ws(" ", $"full_date", $"TimeCST"))
// // df3.show()

val stamp = df3.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"date_time", "M/d/yyyy h:mm a"))
stamp.show()
```

I'm getting 94668798 but it should be 946752780.  An example date I'm trying to convert is this: 1/1/2000 12:53 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `unix_timestamp`:

> Converts time string in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to Unix timestamp (in seconds), **using the default timezone and the default locale.**

In other words, since your timestamp format does not include the timezone, Spark treats the time as being in the timezone configured on the machine running Spark. If you want the value in a different timezone, set `spark.sql.session.timeZone` to the correct name first:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Berlin")
```

Comment: I added that but there was no change.  Its still giving me the same timestamp which translates to GMT: Sunday, December 31, 1972 4:47:18 PM

Comment: That worked changing to Central time but with the previous comment, I can't believe I didn't notice that the last 0 was cut off and added to a the next line...but everything is working now!!!

Comment: @TCL9111 I noticed a zero was missing because the difference between the numbers in your question was not an integer number of hours (or even half hours), but assumed it was merely an error when copy-pasting.